# Electric Field Strength due to a hemisphere (Uniformly charged)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry

I have a uniformly charged hemisphere. I need to find Electric field due to this at the center of it.

[image]

I tried by taking semicircular rings at angle angle $\theta$ and proceeding like this:
Let surface charge density on hemisphere be $\sigma C / m^2$ . Then charge on semicircular ring(at an angle $\theta$) will be $2 \pi R^2  d\theta \sigma$.
$$E = \frac{\lambda}{2 \pi ε_0 R}$$
where $\lambda = Q_{ring} / \pi R =  d\theta{2R} \sigma$

Calculating total electric field :
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 2 E cos \theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sigma cos \theta d\theta}{\pi ε_0} = \frac{\sigma}{\pi ε_0}$$

But this is not the exact answer. Answer comes out different when circular rings(horizontally) are taken.

Comment: which center? The sphere center of the hemisphere center?